# The user is not asked for authentication to login to my site's Wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Recently I have installed WordPress on my Host:

I made a database from MySQL® Database Wizard and defined a user for it.

then I renamed the **wp-config-sample.php** file to **wp-config.php** and change the following records in it based on my own information:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', ‘username_here’);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘password_here’);
```

After that I ran the Wordpress installation and logged into my WordPress Dashboard.

Up to here everything was alright but when I tried to log in to my site's wp-admin (mysite.com/wp-admin) from another browser I realized that without any authentication I just logged in to my Dashboard.

I copied back wp-config-sample.php to my host with its old information mention above (***Now I have both wp-config-sample.php and wp-config.php files but their content are different wp-config.php contains my exact database name and db user details***) and then I tried again, this time I was asked for authentication.

Finally I went to Posts section in my Dashboard and copied the URL from my browser and pasted it in another browser, **again I could login without authentication I could see all posts overview but I couldn't change anything and a message was shown saying that my session has been timed out so I must login again and I was asked to enter my username and password while I was in the Dashboard**

As you know this can make big troubles for me because so many important information can be seen by non-admin users. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you never logged in before in that browser? I always use incognito mode when testing stuff like this.

Comment: @BerenddeGroot Yes, It was the first time that I tried to login through that browser right after the installation. I also tried it on another device which I never used to login to my dashboard before and the result was the same.

Comment: Did you have another WordPress installation on this host before this one?

Comment: @BerenddeGroot No this was the first wp installation on this host.

Comment: Did you import settings from the first browser? Most modern browsers ask you would you like to import settings from other installed browsers.

Comment: @ZacGrierson No as I said I tried in a completely different device and unfortunately the result was same.

Comment: What sort of server infrastructure do you have? Maybe you are caching sessions on the server? Do you change IP addresses?

Comment: @ZacGrierson Hmmm You may be right, I'm using the same IP.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi recreate the issue and try with something like TOR or maybe your cell phones data connection (so it's not on WIFI).